# responsive images with position absolute in bootstrap 3

Tags: responsive-images

I'm new in using bootstrap 3. I need your help on how to make images responsive while using position absolute, top and left? My images are on top of one image and whenever I re-size the browser the images will not be in their place anymore(desktop size).

Comment: can you put your code sample or link to jsfiddle or similar sites having code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

so something like this: (in one of the relevant .css files)

```
img.topleftStuck {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

then something like this:

```
<img src='path/to/crappy_image.gif' class=topleftStuck>
```

this can also be achieved with `div` in similar fashion..  :)